# Can't retrieve persisted object

Tags: java, android, orm

My DatabaseHelper class looks like this:

```java
package de.wlochowitz.myapp;

import spedition.Fahrer;
import spedition.Lagerstaette;
import spedition.ModelModelFactory;
import spedition.Warenannahme;
import android.content.Context;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

import com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper;
import com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao;
import com.j256.ormlite.dao.RuntimeExceptionDao;
import com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource;
import com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils;

public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydb.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private Dao<Fahrer, String> fahrerDao = null;
    private Dao<Lagerstaette, String> lagerstaetteDao = null;
    private Dao<Warenannahme, String> warenannahmeDao = null;
    private RuntimeExceptionDao<Fahrer, String> fahrerRuntimeDao = null;
    private RuntimeExceptionDao<Lagerstaette, String> lagerstaetteRuntimeDao = null;
    private RuntimeExceptionDao<Warenannahme, String> warenannahmeRuntimeDao = null;
    private ModelModelFactory mmf = null;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void dropTables(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connSrc) throws SQLException {
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Fahrer.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Lagerstaette.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Warenannahme.class, true);
    }

    public void createTables(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connSrc) {
        try {
            Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "onCreate");
            TableUtils.createTable(connSrc, Fahrer.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(connSrc, Lagerstaette.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(connSrc, Warenannahme.class);
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't create database");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        Fahrer fahrerA = addFahrer("A", 1);
        Fahrer fahrerB = addFahrer("B", 2);
        Fahrer fahrerC = addFahrer("C", 3);
        Fahrer fahrerD = addFahrer("D", 4);

        Lagerstaette lagerstaette1 = addLagerstaette(20, 1);
        Lagerstaette lagerstaette2 = addLagerstaette(40, 2);
        Lagerstaette lagerstaette3 = addLagerstaette(90, 3);
        Lagerstaette lagerstaette4 = addLagerstaette(30, 4);

        addWarenannahme(1, fahrerA, lagerstaette1, lagerstaette1.getWarenkapazitaet());
        addWarenannahme(2, fahrerB, lagerstaette2, lagerstaette2.getWarenkapazitaet());
        addWarenannahme(3, fahrerC, lagerstaette3, lagerstaette3.getWarenkapazitaet());
        addWarenannahme(4, fahrerD, lagerstaette4, lagerstaette4.getWarenkapazitaet());
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connSrc) {
        createTables(db, connSrc);
    }

    public Fahrer addFahrer(final String name, final long id) {
        Fahrer fahrer = getModelFactory().createFahrer();
        fahrer.setName(name);
        fahrer.setId(id);
        getFahrerDataDao().create(fahrer);
        return fahrer;
    }

    public Lagerstaette addLagerstaette(final int warenkapazitaet, final long id) {
        Lagerstaette lagerstaette = getModelFactory().createLagerstaette();
        lagerstaette.setWarenkapazitaet(warenkapazitaet);
        lagerstaette.setId(id);
        getLagerstaetteDataDao().create(lagerstaette);
        return lagerstaette;
    }

    public Warenannahme addWarenannahme(final long id, final Fahrer fahrer,
            final Lagerstaette lagerstaette, final int kapazitaet) {
        Warenannahme warenannahme = getModelFactory().createWarenannahme();
        warenannahme.setId(id);
        warenannahme.setFahrer(fahrer);
        warenannahme.setLagerstaette(lagerstaette);
        warenannahme.setKapazitaet(kapazitaet);
        getWarenannahmeDataDao().create(warenannahme);
        return warenannahme;
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connSrc, int oldVersion,
            int newVersion) {
        try {
            Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "onUpgrade");
            dropTables(db, connSrc);
            onCreate(db, connectionSource);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't drop databases", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public ModelModelFactory getModelFactory() {
        if(mmf == null) {
            mmf = new ModelModelFactory();
        }
        return mmf;
    }

    public Dao<Fahrer, String> getFahrerDao() throws SQLException {
        if (fahrerDao == null) {
            fahrerDao = getDao(Fahrer.class);
        }
        return fahrerDao;
    }

    public Dao<Lagerstaette, String> getLagerstaetteDao() throws SQLException {
        if (lagerstaetteDao == null) {
            lagerstaetteDao = getDao(Lagerstaette.class);
        }
        return lagerstaetteDao;
    }

    public Dao<Warenannahme, String> getWarenannahmeDao() throws SQLException {
        if (warenannahmeDao == null) {
            warenannahmeDao = getDao(Warenannahme.class);
        }
        return warenannahmeDao;
    }

    public RuntimeExceptionDao<Fahrer, String> getFahrerDataDao() {
        if (fahrerRuntimeDao == null) {
            fahrerRuntimeDao = getRuntimeExceptionDao(Fahrer.class);
        }
        return fahrerRuntimeDao;
    }

    public RuntimeExceptionDao<Lagerstaette, String> getLagerstaetteDataDao() {
        if (lagerstaetteRuntimeDao == null) {
            lagerstaetteRuntimeDao = getRuntimeExceptionDao(Lagerstaette.class);
        }
        return lagerstaetteRuntimeDao;
    }

    public RuntimeExceptionDao<Warenannahme, String> getWarenannahmeDataDao() {
        if (warenannahmeRuntimeDao == null) {
            warenannahmeRuntimeDao = getRuntimeExceptionDao(Warenannahme.class);
        }
        return warenannahmeRuntimeDao;
    }

    public void close() {
        super.close();
        fahrerDao = null;
        fahrerRuntimeDao = null;
        mmf = null;
    }
}
```

My doStuff Method in the MainActivity looks like this:

```java
public void doStuff() throws SQLException {

        ConnectionSource connSrc = getHelper().getConnectionSource();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getHelper().getReadableDatabase();
        getHelper().dropTables(db, connSrc);
        getHelper().createTables(db, connSrc);
        CloseableWrappedIterable<Warenannahme> wrappedIterable =
                getHelper().getWarenannahmeDao().getWrappedIterable();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(Warenannahme warenannahme : wrappedIterable) {
            Fahrer fahrer = warenannahme.getFahrer();
            Lagerstaette lagerstaette = warenannahme.getLagerstaette();
            sb.append(fahrer.getId());
            System.out.println(fahrer.getName());
            sb.append('\t');
            sb.append(lagerstaette.getId());
            System.out.println(lagerstaette.getWarenkapazitaet());
            sb.append('\t');
            sb.append(warenannahme.getKapazitaet());
            sb.append('\n');
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
```

I'm trying to get Fahrer.getName(); of the persisted Fahrer object from Warennahme.

```java
addWarenannahme(1, fahrerA, lagerstaette1, lagerstaette1.getWarenkapazitaet());
addWarenannahme(2, fahrerB, lagerstaette2, lagerstaette2.getWarenkapazitaet());
addWarenannahme(3, fahrerC, lagerstaette3, lagerstaette3.getWarenkapazitaet());
addWarenannahme(4, fahrerD, lagerstaette4, lagerstaette4.getWarenkapazitaet());
```

ORM Lite won't deliver the same fahrer object as added to the warennahme object.

If I try:

```java
for(Warenannahme warenannahme : wrappedIterable) {
            Fahrer fahrer = warenannahme.getFahrer();
            Lagerstaette lagerstaette = warenannahme.getLagerstaette();
            sb.append(fahrer.getId());
            System.out.println(fahrer.getName());
```

I get null for fahrer.getName();

But I should get "A", "B", "C", "D".

Whats wrong?

Please help me.